# A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'. and 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am learning flutter now and study from this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JX2EjA4W85k&list=RDCMUCsPdgUIoOBTBI1UmulW1pdw&index=4&ab_channel=SanskarTiwari

here is the thing since now flutter is updated for null-safety:

```
getUserInfo() async{
    Constants.myName = (await HelperFunctions.getUserNameSharedPreference())!;
  }
```

//error is A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.

here is for `HelperFunctions.getUserNameSharedPreference()`

```
class HelperFunctions{

    static String sharePreferenceUserNameKey = "USERNAMEKEY"; 
    static Future<String?> getUserNameSharedPreference(bool isUserLoggedIn) async{
       SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
       return await prefs.getString(sharePreferenceUserNameKey);
  }    
}
```

I tried the solution like this:

```
getUserInfo() async{
    Constants.myName = (await HelperFunctions.getUserNameSharedPreference())!;
  }
//error is 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.
```

guys, im so confusing what I can do to solve this issue, thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: can you share your `HelperFunctions.getUserNameSharedPreference()` as well in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with null safety Make sure before declaring every variable say string you add a question mark at the front eg String? name